# How do i select the radio button randomly in webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The HTML for the Answer Choices is

```
 A
<input id="A" type="radio" onclick="javascript:ValidateAns(53209,0,9, 'A')" name="AnsChoice" value="A"/>
<label for="A">145</label>
<br/>
<br/>
    B
<input id="B" type="radio" onclick="javascript:ValidateAns(53209,0,9, 'B')" name="AnsChoice" value="B"/>
<label for="B">148</label>
<br/>
<br/>
    C
<input id="C" type="radio" onclick="javascript:ValidateAns(53209,0,9, 'C')" name="AnsChoice" value="C"/>
<label for="C">143</label>
<br/>
<br/>
    D
<input id="D" type="radio" onclick="javascript:ValidateAns(53209,0,9, 'D')" name="AnsChoice" value="D"/>
<label for="D">155</label>
```

Comment: Create a list of the elements, generate a random position in that list and then click on that element.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how useful randomly selecting radio buttons would be as a test.  Tests should be repeatable and verifiable.  This is neither.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Not really a WebDriver problem.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
radios.get(rnd.nextInt(radios.size())).click();
```